# How do I generate all the vectors by swapping two positions?

Tags: r, matrix, combinations

Suppose I have a column vector of [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3] and I want to generate all the different column vectors only by switching two positions. For an example, one such vector would be 
[1 1 3 2 2 2 1 3 3].

Comment: by switching do you mean swapping or changing 1 by either 2 or 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (it gives you a data frame each row of which is a unique vector with 2 elements swapped from the original vector, there are 28 such unique vectors, including the original one):

```
v <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
unique(t(apply(t(combn(1:length(v), 2)), 1, function(x) {v[x] <- v[rev(x)]; v})))
```

with output:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 [1,]    1    1    1    2    2    2    3    3    3 # original one
 [2,]    2    1    1    1    2    2    3    3    3 # swap 1st & 4th elements
 [3,]    2    1    1    2    1    2    3    3    3 # swap 1st & 5th
 [4,]    2    1    1    2    2    1    3    3    3 # ...
 [5,]    3    1    1    2    2    2    1    3    3
 [6,]    3    1    1    2    2    2    3    1    3
 [7,]    3    1    1    2    2    2    3    3    1
 [8,]    1    2    1    1    2    2    3    3    3
 [9,]    1    2    1    2    1    2    3    3    3
[10,]    1    2    1    2    2    1    3    3    3
[11,]    1    3    1    2    2    2    1    3    3
[12,]    1    3    1    2    2    2    3    1    3
[13,]    1    3    1    2    2    2    3    3    1
[14,]    1    1    2    1    2    2    3    3    3
[15,]    1    1    2    2    1    2    3    3    3
[16,]    1    1    2    2    2    1    3    3    3
[17,]    1    1    3    2    2    2    1    3    3
[18,]    1    1    3    2    2    2    3    1    3
[19,]    1    1    3    2    2    2    3    3    1
[20,]    1    1    1    3    2    2    2    3    3
[21,]    1    1    1    3    2    2    3    2    3
[22,]    1    1    1    3    2    2    3    3    2
[23,]    1    1    1    2    3    2    2    3    3
[24,]    1    1    1    2    3    2    3    2    3
[25,]    1    1    1    2    3    2    3    3    2
[26,]    1    1    1    2    2    3    2    3    3
[27,]    1    1    1    2    2    3    3    2    3
[28,]    1    1    1    2    2    3    3    3    2  # swap 6th & 9th
```

Answer (score 1):

First, we can use the `utils` function `combn` to generate all of the possible combinations of pairs of positions to swap. Here, I am assuming you don't want to swap the same number (e.g. 1 and 1), so am checking them to make sure they are different values:

```
allCombo <-
  combn(1:length(startVec), 2)

toKeep <- apply(allCombo, 2, function(x) {
  startVec[x[1]] != startVec[x[2]]
  })
```

Then, apply along those that you are keeping, and swap the positions.

```
outVecs <- apply(allCombo[ , toKeep], 2, function(x){
  temp <- startVec
  temp[x] <- startVec[rev(x)]
  return(temp)
})
```

This returns as a vector, but you can convert it to a list, which may be easier to manage, like so:

```
outVecsInList <-
  as.list(as.data.frame(outVecs))
```

`head(outVecsInList)` shows:

```
$V1
[1] 2 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3

$V2
[1] 2 1 1 2 1 2 3 3 3

$V3
[1] 2 1 1 2 2 1 3 3 3

$V4
[1] 3 1 1 2 2 2 1 3 3

$V5
[1] 3 1 1 2 2 2 3 1 3

$V6
[1] 3 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 1
```